# Chrome : Display image that when clicked launches external Windows app

Tags: google-chrome-extension, npapi, firebreath

i want to develop an extension in Chrome that will display an image
above an html element that when clicked will launch an external Windows app.

Is it necessary to develop a NPAPI Plugin for such a thing?

Is there a simpler way to call an external app with Chrome?

Do you know any good and simple tutorials for NPAPI Plugin Development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows app can register a [custom protocol handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can register a custom protocol for the app that will pass the image URL to the app. E.g. `myapp://example.com/img.png` or something similar.

A good example of this is iTunes. It registers `itms` and [online app pages](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google+/id447119634?mt=8) offer to open iTunes to the app specified. The URL opened is `itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google+/id447119634?mt=8`.

Comment: abraham's answer is the way you should go...but theres also an extension that has a plugin that can you could use to launch an app from Chrome....  http://www.chromeextensions.org/other/simple-get/

Comment: basically i want to make a youtube video downloader button.
this means that i have to parse the page, find the elements that are videos and then display an image above them that when pressed launches my application.

do you know how i should do this ?